# mapDispatchToProps function is undefined

Tags: redux, react-redux

I am trying to get redux working in my react-native app. Basically, I have a signIn action defined in my authActions.js file:

```
const signInAction = () => {
    return {
        type: 'signIn',
    };
};

export { signInAction };
```

Then I have an authReducer defined as this in authReducer.js:

```
const initialState = {
    isAuthenticated: false,

}

const authReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

    switch(action.type) {

        case "signIn": 
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                isAuthenticated: true,

            })


        default: return state;
    }

};

export default authReducer;
```

I combine that reducer in my rootReducer.js file

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import auth from 'app/src/redux/reducers/authReducer.js';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    auth,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

and then created a store in reduxIndex.js:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from 'app/src/redux/reducers/rootReducer.js';

let store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware));
export default store;
```

I wrapped my app in a `<Provider>` component, and that seems to be working fine (I can read from the state and see the value of isAuthenticated. However, when I try to dispatch an action using mapDispatchToProps in one of my views the function is undefined:

```
// More imports 
// ... 

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { signInAction } from 'app/src/redux/actions/authActions.js';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {};
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onSignIn: () => { dispatch(signInAction) },
  };
}
class SignIn extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: "",
    }
  }

  onSignInPress() {
    // ******* this is where the error occurrs ****
    this.props.onSignIn();
  }

  render() {

    const {navigation} = this.props;

    return (

            <View style={SignInStyles.container}>
              <ScrollView>
                <View>


                  <Button 
                    large 
                    title="SIGN IN"
                    backgroundColor={colors.primary}
                    onPress={this.onSignInPress}
                  />
                </View>

              </ScrollView>
            </View>


    );

  }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SignIn);
```

I cant really see where I am going wrong, but im sure its a simple mistake somewhere. The specific error I get is :

"undefined is not an object. Evaluating this.props.onSignIn"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `onSignInPress` callback isn't bound to any particular object, so when it gets called `this` is `undefined`.

The easy way to fix it is to use arrow syntax to make it always be bound.  In your class definition:

```
onSignInPress = () => {
  this.props.onSignIn();
}
```

Google found me [this Medium article from Miron Machnicki](https://medium.com/@machnicki/handle-events-in-react-with-arrow-functions-ede88184bbb) which explains the differences and possible alternative syntaxes in pretty good detail.

Comment: Hey! that fixed it! Im very new to JS so i keep getting tripped up by the binding of this every now and then. Can you answer a question for me? My render method isnt defined using the fat arrow syntax, yet it still has this bound correctly. How does that work?